# Is it Possible to Record Wii U Footage without an Elgato?

Tags: wii-u

So, I was wondering if it is possible to record Wii U footage without using an elgato, or capture card. I don't need it in HD, but I just need the footage on my computer.

Comment: You can take screenshots. There is no video recording functionality built-in, however.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to take screenshots?

Comment: I think you need to launch the Miiverse. Once it's running, you can post messages. Before you post the message, you can attach a screenshot of either the TV's content, or the gamepad's. I know it's not very practical, but that's the current situation with the Wii U. Maybe the NX will do it better? Or maybe not.

Comment: @Nolonar yeah but miiverse takes 2 mins to load

Comment: @Nolonar Thanks for the help, but I had already known how to do that. Thank you for helping, but I don't think that you can save the images posted to Miiverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native support for video recording on the Wii U.  You can get fairly cheap ($10) [composite only video capture adapters](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=video+capture), but just know that the quality on them can be quite poor.

Comment: Thanks! I had also watched a few videos about people connecting their cameras to their television out ports, and the out ports go into the camera. Is that possible?

Comment: @LionScratch, Some cameras can accept video in directly, but it depends on the camera.  I don't think I've owned a TV that had video out, at least not in recent history.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. In the video I saw, the TV screen was quite old, and was not a flatscreen.